# regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I find regular expressions pretty tough to understand in python. The documentation is too cryptic. For instance what would be the re for removing all instances of `#if DEBUG` and everything enclosed between it and its corresponding `#endif` in a C file. The following is not working:

```
 buf = file.read()
 a = re.compile("#if.DEBUG?#endif", re.MULTILINE + re.DOTALL)  
 string1 = re.sub(p_macro, '', buf)
```

Comment: Some example input and desired output please...

Comment: Don't know exactly what you need/want. Try http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. It's not python, but it's invaluable to try and test your regular expressions.

Comment: in your example you are compiling the regex but how did you applied it?

Comment: Is this homework? `#if` statements may be nested, so they can't be correctly handled using regular expressions.

Comment: Regular expression is a common meta-language. This is not Python-specific. That is, what makes this tough to understand, would also make it tough to understand in, say, Perl or Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all instances of #if DEBUG all you have to do is define DEBUG to 0, and run the preprocessor on it. No need for nasty regular expressions.

Also, it's generally not a good idea to operate on a context free grammar (C source, for example, or more notoriously, html) using regular expressions. Use a parsing library. Check out the eclipse sdk for example: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/overview-summary.html

Comment: @hop: thanks :-). I like to keep things simple whenever possible. I should say that the link I gave won't work for C, because it's the jdt reference. For parsing C and C++ you want the cdt libraries (they're in the same page, just search for "cdt").

Answer (score 1):

Python's RegEx uses most of the syntax from PCRE. You could learn some of them from http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.

Your code does not work because

```
  #if.DEBUG?#endif
//        ^^
```

the `G?` actually means "one or zero `G` character".

If you want to remove the whole `#if DEBUG` block, try

```
re.compile(
    r'^\s*#if\s+DEBUG'    # match the '#if DEBUG' preprocessor.
    r'.*?'                # match all content in between until...
    r'^\s*#endif'         # ... getting a '#endif' and match it
,
    re.S|re.M
)
```

but it will not work with nested `#if` blocks, and it won't check if the preprocessor is within a comment `/* ... */`. It's better to use a CPP parser for correctness.

Comment: thanks do you mean that if the file contains #ifs other #if DEDBUG your re will not work ? for instance file contains things like #if 0, #if TRUE and #if DEBUG and thier corresponding #endifs , it will not work

Comment: @don: `#if 0` will not be recognized by this regex and is kept intact.

Comment: @don: It only checks DEBUG. If you want to check for 0 or FALSE too, replace that `DEBUG` with `(?:DEBUG|0|FALSE)`.

Comment: That means if there is something #if DEBUG ... #if something ... #endif ... #endif will not work

Answer (score 0):

If [Kodos](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/), the **Python Regular Expression Debugger**, is available on your development platform, you'll have an easier time crafting and testing regular expressions.